# Notify.JS : Notify on a speficic element not working when page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, notify

I a have probleme in my MVC .NET application when i use notify.js.

I use this library to display some informations in all my website, but I just realized that in every pages when I scroll the position of my notify is not working !

I try to notify on a specific element like that :

```
  $('#idOfMyElement').notify("Notify text", { position: "top center", className: "success", autoHideDelay: 1500 });
```

It's working unless i scroll ...  When I scroll the notify is displaying in the same position as if i didn't scroll ! Like the notify is fixed on the previous element's position on the screen...

- My libraries are up to date, like bootstrap / jquery / notify.js

Please help, i can't reproduce this in a jsfiddle ...

Comment: According to the website: https://notifyjs.com/ the notification is displayed on an element or on a fixed part of the page that does not change when you scroll: `$.notify("I'm over here !");` I'm not sure you want fixed or global but the code you posted is a fixed notification so the element should scroll up and down with the element.

Comment: Global fixed element is displayed very well. I want to display informations on a element of my webpage. It's working until i scroll, and i think that the notifications doesn't update the current position of my element and is displayed in it's initial position, not it's new position.

Comment: Looking at the examples on the notify.js site I can see the notification is nested in the element it is attached to so when you scroll the notification sticks to the whatever element you attached it to unless you have some overriding styles to the notification that make it's position fixed.

Comment: I don't have any override style .. That's why i'm stuck. I'll keep searching.

Comment: Same comportment when i remove all the css in my view ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.

I couldn't understand why on notify.js web worked fine, and not on mine.

So I just changed the jquery version and it started working fine.

I used jquery 3.0.0 on my website and it gave this problem, and on notify.js website it uses 1.11.

I have tested that it works fine with jquery 1.11, 2.2.4, and 3.5.1 (which is the one I have now)